Why is stdout behaving unbuffered by default? (mingw-w64 gcc)
I've been doing some exercises with printing to streams in C.
Today I've been a bit confused: as I understand in most implementations of the C standard library, the default behaviour of stdout is block buffered (or line buffered when connected to a terminal), but in my case it seems to be unbuffered.
For example, the following always prints before entering the infinite loop:
# include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    fputs("a", stdout);
    while (1);
    return 0;
}

I can force the behaviour I need by setting setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 1024);, but I'm still confused by the default.
Is this expected behaviour when using gcc as provided by mingw-w64, or am I missing something?
Thanks!

Do you mean that the string "a" is always printed immediately? How do you build your program? How do you run it? In what environment are you running it (IDE, editor, console)?

No, this is not expected behavior. What is stdout connected to?

It might be helpful to know that (IIRC) MinGW is by default using the MSVC runtime library. So your fputs will actually use the MSVC function, not something made for GCC.

@Someprogrammerdude Yes I mean that "a" is always printed immediately. I simply build from the command line with gcc filename.c -o filename.exe and then get the mentioned behaviour when running in cmd or the VsCode terminal.

Under linux, stdout is default line buffer to terminal (default buffered if stdout points to a file or pipe). AFAIK, there is no rule that specifies the default buffering? So, winX could default to unbuffered. (i.e.) The terminal emulator/window and/or the low level code you're running under could have different rules.

I can reproduce with x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (MinGW-W64 x86_64-msvcrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 13.1.0

@CraigEstey: There is a rule, but it does not rule out unbuffered in this case. C 2018 7.21.3 7 says that standard output is fully buffered if and only if it can be determined not to refer to an interactive device. So, if it is connected to a terminal, it must be line buffered or unbuffered.

@Eric Postpischil But look at the definition of line-buffered in paragraph 3. "Support for these characteristics is implementation-defined, and may be affected via the setbuf and setvbuf functions." (Emphasis mine)

The Windows terminal is by default not line buffered on output.

@Dúthomhas, It is in Perl, and could just as easily be in C. It has nothing to do with the OS.

It could be, but isn’t. And it has everything to do with the OS. (This is the way the terminal has always worked, and is one of those things that trip people up when moving to *nixen.)

@Dúthomhas Did you mean "stdio on Windows" when you said Windows terminal? It's not the terminal that provides buffering, it's the C library.  /// Re "This is the way the terminal has always worked", Nope. The terminal knows nothing of buffering. Use strace or similar to verify if you don't believe me.

It presumably depends on the C runtime library. Different compilers may use different libraries, and the one that MinGW uses doesn't buffer output to terminals. This one seems to be provided by the OS.

The behavior of the terminal on Windows is not buffered, and MS libc does not buffer when connected to the terminal. Other libc implementations for use on Windows maintain that behavior.

@Dúthomhas Re "The behavior of the terminal on Windows is not buffered", Just like Linux. Saying it a third time isn't going to make it relevant.

Whether it is windows or the clib implementation, I can safely assume this is default behaviour. And just use setvbuf where necessary?

@ikegami: Yes, so? Craig Estey said they did not know of a rule, so I informed them of the rule. And I noted it does not rule out unbuffered. setbuf and setvbuf are not involved here; they were not called in OP’s program and so did not affect standard output.

@Dúthomhas: The Windows terminal device might immediately display any characters sent to it, but that is irrelevant here. The buffering of streams is implemented in the C standard library. If a stream is buffered or line-buffered, the C library software does not immediately send characters to the connected device. They are held in a buffer inside the C program, and the terminal knows nothing of them.

@EricPostpischil Re "so I informed them of the rule.", You also said "So, if it is connected to a terminal, it must be line buffered or unbuffered." ///  Re "Yes, so?", The behaviour is actually implementation-defined.

@ikegami: Again, what is your point? Are you saying the rules have no meaning because “implementation-defined” gives the implementation latitude to do anything? (That is not the intent. It allows the implementation to specify a buffer size or perhaps to specify line-buffered is not supported, so unbuffered will be used when the standard gives the option of line-buffered or unbuffered.) Or are you trying to make some point that the implementation can make the stream unbuffered because something is implementation-defined? That is pointless, as unbuffered is already an option. What is your point?

Related: Is stdout line buffered, unbuffered or indeterminate by default?

@Eric Postpischil, Re "gives the implementation latitude to do anything?", Pretty much, yes. The standard says to use line-buffering, but then says the implementation doesn't actually have to use line-buffering. In other words, it's merely a strongly-worded recommendation.

@ikegami: “Implementation-defined” does not give the implementation any additional license. It is a requirement: The implementation must document what choices it makes. It is still subject to the rules of the C standard. An implementation may define what buffer size it uses and whether it makes standard output to a terminal be line buffered or unbuffered. It is not freed from the general rules about buffering and is not free to do anything.

@Eric Postpischil, No, It says it must be line-buffered, but it says the definition of line-buffered is flushed on LF if supported by the implementation. It doesn't say what should happen if line-buffering isn't supported.

@ikegami: Re “No, It says it must be line-buffered”: C 2018 7.21.3 7 says that standard output that cannot be determined to refer to an interactive device is not fully buffered. That means it must be line buffered or unbuffered. It does not say it must be line buffered. Re “it says the definition of line-buffered is flushed on LF if supported by the implementation”: No, it does not say the definition of line buffered depends on the implementation. The standard defines line buffered for itself. It says support for the buffering characteristics is implementation defined. You might, conceivably…

… take that two ways. One is it merely means the particular details of buffering are implementation-defined: An implementation defines how it implements buffering, such as the buffer size it uses, but not whether it implements buffering. Another is that the implementation does define whether it implements each buffering mode. However, defining whether an implementation supports each mode would not change the meaning of what the mode is. If an implementation did not support line buffering, it remains subject to the requirement that standard output to a terminal not be fully buffered…

… So it would have to be unbuffered.
